# C# Split - Split on list dont return all the wanted strings

Tags: c#, list, split

I'm fairly new to C#, and i've come across a problem trying to split on list elements.
I have a resource file containing string properties as such:
[ResourceFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79KCa.png)
[ResourceFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glk2F.png)

I've collected them in a List as:

```
public List<String> RawNewsList1 = new List<String>()
{
  {Resource.NewsContentAndroid1},
  {Resource.NewsMetaAndroid1},
};
```

I'm trying to split on the semicolons but only get results from my second list item.
My split look like this:

```
public void FilterRawNews()
{
  String[] seperator = { ";;;" };
  String[] filteredList1 = { "" };

  for (int i = 0; i < RawNewsList1.Count; i++) {

    filteredList1 = RawNewsList1[i].Split(seperator, 5,
         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

  }

  foreach (String s in filteredList1)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    
  }
}
```

Its only prints:

110

2.8

02-07-2020

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: .Split(seperator, 5, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];

Comment: If you try to debug your code, you will notice that _filteredList1_ is first filled with data from your first resource, then at the next loop your variable's content is _replaced_ with  the data coming from the second resource.

Comment: As you see it's only reading the last cell of your 2nd Resource. Run your code in debug mode to see if all the values are getting read into RawNewsList1, then go from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *filteredList1* variable is first filled with data from your the first resource, then at the next loop the variable's content is replaced with the data coming from the second resource.

You can use a `List<string>` instead that has the AddRange method to continuosly add elements to the list

```
List<string> filteredList1 = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < RawNewsList1.Count; i++) {

    filteredList1.AddRange(RawNewsList1[i].Split(seperator, 5,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

}
```

From this we could simplify the code to one-liner with

```
filteredList = RawNewsList1.SelectMany(a => a.Split(seperator,5, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToList();
```

So, what's happen in that single line? That syntax is used when you work with objects that can be treated as a sequence of data. In this context your array RawNewsList1 is a sequence of data and we can use the IEnumerable extensions brought to us by using the Linq namespace. The *SelectMany* extension requires a lambda expression ( a => ....) that is used to produce the instructions where each element of the sequence (*a*) is passed to an expression that returns another sequence of data (the array returned by Split). The sequence returned is accumulated to the sequence produced by the next elements from the original *RasNewsList1*. Finally the accumulated sequence is *materialized* with the call to *ToList()*

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting filteredList1 in each iteration.
That is why you only get the last result.

Just declare filteredList1 as a list and and use AddRange().

Edit: or use LINQ:

```csharp
var raw = new List<string>() { "111;;;222", "333;;;444" };
String[] seperator = { ";;;" };

var filterlist1 = raw.SelectMany(r => r.Split(seperator, 5, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToList();
```